# MapsForge 0.4.0 API doc for Android

Tags: android, class, deprecated, mapsforge

Do somebody have any information where can I found a good API doc for MapsForge 0.4.0 libraries?
Since version 0.3.0 many more classes changed to deprecated, and there are some more new functionality. I do not know which classes can I use instead of deprecated classes. 
I found some examples, but I don't want to copy sources instead I would to read the API docs

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Best place to read about that is [Here](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/tree/master/docs)

And I suggest you take a look at [This](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-Developers.md) which is a quick description for developers of how to get started with mapsforge.

And [This](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-Android-App.md)--> A very basic Android app example